Google business profile always shows as 'Incomplete'
I have a Google account to which I added a business profile many years ago.
In the last year or so I've been paying more attention to the way my business is displayed by Google in Search and Maps.
Google always displays a 'Complete your profile' link to me, which I can't get rid of no matter what I've tried.

I've clicked on the link and entered all the information requested of me.
I called the support center but didn't get a solution.
I emailed support but didn't get a response.
I followed instructions from a video I found to add funds to my 'adsense' account and advertise my business, but there was no change.
I switched from a free account to a paid Google Workspace account with no change.
I've reviewed a lot of Google documentation to no avail.

Additional Notes

My business is set up to collect genuine reviews from customers
I've tried searching for my business on customer phones within a 50km radius of my business address, but if it is shown at all, it's found under 'more' which is accessed after the third result shown.

How can I complete my business profile that is shown in Maps and Search results?




Google Maps is optimized for showing places that people can visit, like restaurants, grocery stores or schools.
If your service doesn't require people to visit the business place, you might not add details like service hours and place "seats". This might be the reason why you see the "Complete info".
Another thing that might need to be added is a list of prices or instructions for requesting a service quote.
Resources

Business Profile FAQs
Edit your business info - Google Business Profile Help
This is a topic page. This means that it includes links to help articles, in this case related to editing business info.

